# Как распределить нагрузку между серверами с nginx-rtmp-module?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

Подскажите как правильно распределять зрителей между серверами с [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)?
К примеру есть 3 сервера на каждом установлен nginx-rtmp-module, rtmp поток создается на первом сервере, как отправить зрителей на 2 сервер если их больше чем может держать первый и так же со второго на третий.

Answer (score 1):

RTMP протокол поддерживает редирект. Т.е. при подключении к серверу, если он не сможет обслужить клиента, он может его перенаправить дальше. Плюс балансировщик на входе.

Схематически это должно выглядеть так:

1. в настройках application (терминология RTMP) добавляется http-колбек (терминология nginx-rtmp) [`on_connect`](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_connect).
2. в обработчике этих сообщений нужно принять решение о редиректе и ответить согласно документации:

   > If HTTP 2xx code is returned then RTMP session continues. *The code of
   >   **3xx** makes RTMP redirect to another application whose name is taken
   >   from **Location** HTTP response header*. Otherwise connection is dropped.

Ещё интересные колбеки:

- [`on_publish`](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_publish) - вызывается при начале публикации стрима на сервер
- [`on_play`](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_play) - вызывается при начале проигрывания стрима с сервера. Он позволяет делать редирект только внутри тещкущего сервера или создавать remove-proxy к другому серверу, оставаясь сам на обслуживании данного клиента.

Т.е. копать детально нужно в сторону `on_connect`.

Как реализовать планирование... Тут вопрос сложный. Как минимум планировщик должен знать о нагрузке всех серверов и динамически принимать решение о перенаправлении. Можно, к примеру, мониторить нагрузку каждого сервера:

- CPU
- Память
- Число подключений
- Утилизация канала

строить рейтинг. Если для текущего сервера какой-то параметр вышел за пределы нормы, то брать сервер с максимальным рейтингом и отправлять подключение туда. В качестве дополнительной, но более сложной меры, можно, со временем научить создавать дополнительные инстансы серверов, причём с учётом скорости роста (например при лавинном подключении при трансляции какого-то эвента) и гасить их по мере спада нагрузки.

Ещё нюансом может стать то, что документация на `on_connect` не говорит явно, что будет, если в *Location* вернуть полный путь с *rtmp://...*. Нужно изучать исходники или спрашивать в рассылке или у автора в почте.

Если такой редирект не поддерживается, то можно попытаться решить вопрос при помощи балансировщиков типа Balance NG или HAProxy. Подобный пример даже рассмотрет в официальном блоге: http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/09/21/high-available-rtmp-platform-with-haproxy-and-crtmpserver/. Единственно, нужно как-то привязать ваш супер-визор. Если мне не изменяет память, то HAProxy можно попросить использовать какой-то скрипт для принятия решения.

Кстати, при живом стриминге, вам нужно будет обеспечить, что бы на тот сервер, на который вы перенаправляете клиента, этот поток тоже присутствовал, т.е. реализовывать релей: публицирует-то один человек и на один сервер.

Answer (score 0):

[Модуль ngx_http_upstream_module позволяет описывать группы серверов, которые могут использоваться в директивах proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)